# Função para Abrir Calendarview clicando no RelayoutLayout

Tags: android

Tenho uma tela onde eu gostaria que o usuário clicasse e abrisse o calendário nativo do sistema. Só que gostaria que o `CalendarView` fosse aberto mesmo se clicasse no `RelativeLayout` que o encobre. Já dei um ID para o `RelativeLayout`, mas como abro o `CalendarView`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Java pra pegar a data:

```
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int years, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + years, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Código XML

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView37"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:text="@string/datapgto"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Essa data é para ser dada apenas através do calendário ou pode ser dada pelo teclado?

Comment: Através do calendário apenas. Quando eu clico abra o calendário, depois seleciono a data e ele insere no campo a data que eu escolhi.

Comment: @Bruno. Tenho dúvidas que a sua edição traduza o que o AP quer perguntar. No original nada indica que ele não saiba abrir o Calendar.

Comment: @ramaral, que bom que o Bruno editou. Porque era essa minha mesma pergunta. Talvez não soube me expressar.

Comment: Podia ter dito na minha resposta. Fiquei com a ideia que ela tinha respondido à pergunta. Você tem ou não o código para o método `chamarCalendar()`? Onde está esse *CalendarView*?

Comment: @ramaral Não tenho o método ainda. Estava olhando aqui na internet uns tutoriais e vi o mesmo código que postei ai encima. No tutorial só tinha isso. E o dele funcionou corretamente, a unica diferença é que ele tinha um botão na tela para chamar o calendario. No meu caso eu tenho um RelativeLayout todo.

Comment: Não posso ter a certeza mas em principio o código que deve por no método `chamarCalendar` será aquele que está no *onClickListener* do botão que você falou.

Comment: Vou entrar em contato com o dono do tutorial para entender melhor o que ele fez lá. Pois como falei antes, o mesmo código que postei ai ele fez. Obrigado pela ajuda, amigos.

Answer (score 1):

Para interceptar o "click" no *RelativeLayout* adicione um `OnClickListener()` a ele:

```
layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Layout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        chamarCalendar();
    }
});
```

Se quiser que ao clicar no *EditeText* chame o calendário em vez do teclado acrescente isto:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EditText clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        chamarCalendar();
        return true;
    }
});
```

O código deve ser colocado no método `onCreate()` da *Activity*

Comment: Ramaral não consegui fazer. Você pode me explicar melhor e com mais detalhes ? Obrigado.

Comment: Você é que tem de dar mais detalhes. O que quer dizer com "não consegui fazer"?

Comment: Ta cara, fica calmo. Relaxa. Te explico melhor. Quando coloco esse código no meu projeto ele manda criar uma variável local chamada editText. Também o método chamarCalendar() não tenho que criar ?

Comment: O método *chamarCalendar()* deve ser criado por si e colocar nele o código que (suponho) você já tem para chamar o calendário. Tem de declarar as variáveis `layout` e `editText`, pode fazê-lo na própria linha ou na *Activity*.

Comment: Obrigado cara..